# jps command on name node shows secondary name node

Tags: hadoop

I have **Hadoop-2.7.1** and I have configured a cluster consists of three nodes.

when I call `jps` command on name node i am getting the following output

```
3234 SecondaryNameNode    
3039 NameNode    
9019 Jps   
3382 ResourceManager
```

calling `jps` command on secondary name node output is

```
4720 DataNode
4826 NodeManager
4949 Jps
```

calling `jps` command on data node output is

```
4824 Jps
4587 DataNode
4701 NodeManager
```

Is this output right? why `jps` shows  `secondarynamenode` on name node and showing data node on secondary name node

isn't there any conflict!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have used `start-all.sh` or `start-dfs.sh` to start the daemons and have not set the property `dfs.namenode.secondary.http-address` in `hdfs-site.xml`.

In that case, `secondarynamenode` will be started in the same node from where the `start-dfs(all).sh` script is executed. To start it in a different node, add this property to `hdfs-site.xml`

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.secondary.http-address</name>
    <value>secondary_namenode_hostname:50090</value>
</property>
```

Datanodes are started based on the hostname(s) listed in the `slaves` file.

Alternatively, use `hadoop-daemon.sh` and `yarn-daemon.sh` scripts to start the specific HDFS and YARN services respectively on each node.

Comment: thanks very much for the reply it was really helpful ,but if i don't want my secondary name node to be a datanode, what should i do? becuase jps on secondary name node after editing hdfs-site.xml shows that secondary name node is  a data node too

Comment: You have to edit your `slaves` file. List only the IPs or hostnames of the nodes where you want to run the `datanode` daemon.

Comment: is there any web reference that tells me about these facts you we were mentioning becuase i have never found these details through my short duration in serach about hadoop appache

Comment: This [link](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/ClusterSetup.html) should help. (y)

Comment: useful link that addresses this issue https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/GettingStartedWithHadoop

Comment: It is for Hadoop1. The `masters` file is not part of hadoop configuration any more.